# uploading image to mysql db by php

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I got my `insert.php` file:

```
<?php

// Above is code for connection //
echo "succesful connection";

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILE['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id`, `image`, `image_name`) VALUES ('1', '{$image}', '{$image_name}')";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    echo "Something went wrong! :("; 
}

?>
```

my `form.php` file:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>File: </label><input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When I want to upload image i got an error:

> "Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in /myDomain.com/insert.php"

---

Update:

I shortened it to:

```
 <?php
 $content = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id`, `image`) VALUES ('1', '{$content}')";
 if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
 echo "Something went wrong! :("; 
 ?>
```

Is added to the database, but not in binary form.

Comment: Why would you want to insert the image into the database to begin with?  There are VERY few use cases where this actually makes sense.

Comment: You forgot the MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field

Comment: You are doing everything wrong. `addslashes` won't save people from uploading malicious scripts, (which you should be worried about) instead of the file name. I don't even know where you go the idea. If you are lazy, [then use this script](https://github.com/simon-eQ/BulletProof) Plus, your database is highly vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Questions like "what and why" doesn't help me at all. It's for test and firstly I have to do it and then I will care of other things. 
In this form it doesn't work, but It should... According to lots of examples.

Comment: You should be using `$_FILES`, not `$_FILE`.

Comment: @keid is my answer helpful? you still need help?

Comment: I've updated my question in first post

Answer (score 0):

Always add check to make sure you are actually getting something,

You can make use of [is_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) Try it like this:

```
<?php
  if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']){
     echo "succesful connection, we have an image!";
    //get the image name, no need for slashes
    $image_name  = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);     
    //perform the the INSERT HERE
    //........
  }else{
      echo "Nothing was uploaded";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you don't want to really store the file in the database. You just want to save the path.

If that is what you want, this script should do it.

```
// Get destination
$destination =  'path/to/folder' . $_FILES['image']['name'];

// Upload file
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);

// Get name
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

// Query
$sql = "INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id`, `image`, `image_name`) VALUES ('1', '{$destination}', '{$image_name}')";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    echo "Something went wrong! :("; 
}
```